# API to monitor EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

CA UIM [probe](https://docops.ca.com/ca-spectrum/10-2-3/en/integrating/ca-spectrum-and-ca-uim/supporting-aws-amazon-web-services-cloud-monitoring) monitors EC2 instances, using API provided by AWS.

Can I get access to this AWS API for monitoring EC2 instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use AWS REST API (available via [SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk) or [CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)). To get instance metrics you'll need to use [EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and [CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) APIs. Here are the examples with AWS CLI for the metrics from ["AWS related QOS Metrics"](https://docops.ca.com/ca-spectrum/10-2-3/en/integrating/ca-spectrum-and-ca-uim/supporting-aws-amazon-web-services-cloud-monitoring#SupportingAWS(AmazonWebServices)CloudMonitoring-AWSrelatedQOSMetrics) of the doc you've provided:

**Instance State**:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[State]"

[
    [
        [
            {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

**CPU Utilization (%)**:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name CPUUtilization  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00

{
    "Label": "CPUUtilization",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T02:40:00Z",
            "Average": 0.0,
            "Unit": "Percent"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T13:35:00Z",
            "Average": 1.0,
            "Unit": "Percent"
        },
        …
    ]
}
```

**Disk Read Ops**:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name EBSReadOps  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name DiskReadOps  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00

{
    "Label": "EBSReadOps",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T00:25:00Z",
            "Average": 10.0,
            "Unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T20:10:00Z",
            "Average": 11.5,
            "Unit": "Count"
        },
        …
    ]
}
```

**Disk Write Ops**

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name EBSWriteOps  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name DiskWriteOps  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00

{
    "Label": "EBSWriteOps",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T00:25:00Z",
            "Average": 1229.3,
            "Unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T20:10:00Z",
            "Average": 496.6,
            "Unit": "Count"
        },
        …
    ]
}
```

**Disk Read Bytes**

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name EBSReadBytes  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name DiskReadBytes  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00

{
    "Label": "EBSReadBytes",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T00:25:00Z",
            "Average": 665.6,
            "Unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T20:10:00Z",
            "Average": 200.3,
            "Unit": "Count"
        },
        …
    ]
}
```

**Disk Write Bytes**

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name EBSWriteBytes  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name DiskWriteBytes  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00

{
    "Label": "EBSWriteBytes",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T00:25:00Z",
            "Average": 7026688.0,
            "Unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T20:10:00Z",
            "Average": 7586713.6,
            "Unit": "Count"
        },
        …
    ]
}
```

**Network In Bytes**

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name NetworkIn  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00

{
    "Label": "NetworkIn",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T16:10:00Z",
            "Average": 24489418.6,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T13:50:00Z",
            "Average": 21305249.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        …
    ]
}
```

**Network Out Bytes**

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name NetworkOut  --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-999f9f99f999f99f9 --start-time 2018-12-07T00:00:00 --end-time 2018-12-08T00:00:00

{
    "Label": "NetworkOut",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T16:10:00Z",
            "Average": 25363795.4,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-07T13:50:00Z",
            "Average": 22128487.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        },
        …
    ]
}
```

The full list of available metrics can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aws-services-cloudwatch-metrics.html). Subpages contain available metrics for particular services. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html) is the page for EC2.

You'll get virtually the same data when using your language's SDK. As you see, CloudWatch just returns a list of timestamped metrics that you've queried.